# Is my B1/B2 visa for USA from India valid after a name change?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I currently hold a valid B1/B2 visa for the USA from India. However this visa is printed in my old passport and has my old name i.e. Namita Piyus Agarwal. I have changed my name to Namita Asnani, and I have a fresh passport with this name. **Will I be granted entry into the United States with my visa, or will I have to obtain a fresh visa?** I have legal papers documenting the name change, including newspaper publications and court affidavits, I will also carry my old passport.

I understand that for some countries the embassy websites say very clearly that it should not be an issue, especially if you have legal documentation of the name change, eg. UK, Turkey etc. There are also some countries for which the US State Department requires a fresh visa to be issued. For India however, this is what the embassy website says: *"If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from the United States."*

Comment: The DoS recommendation seems quite clear, do you have a reason to doubt its reliability?

Comment: You have done some homework which is good. And your homework indicates it’s **recommended** you apply for a new visa to make it easier. There’s really nothing more we can add. I will say this however. Applying for USA visas from a developing country can be a crapshoot with strange results. If for some reason your immigration profile has changed for the worse & there’s a significant possibility of being denied, I would take my chances with using the old visa. Remember there’s also the a possible hassle with the airline refusing you boarding. The choice is yours to roll the dice or not.

Comment: @Traveller The DoS recommendation wasn't very clear to me, they used the word "recommended". They also use the word "easier". I don't really know what that means. Unfortunately I must travel for business purposes this month itself, but I will not be able to secure a visa appointment and hence a fresh visa in this time, so I guess I will just have to give it a shot :), and hope they don't send me back from the US port of entry.